# How to (re)set permissions for a Service in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, services

I have a client XP machine that logs onto the network via dial-up connection. In the process of identifying and removing a worm on the client, the permissions for Remote Access Connection Manager got changed. Don't ask how, it is beside the point. All permissions were removed (Full, Read, etc.) for ALL users.

The service will not start (obviously), and when I right-click it in the services console, all the options at the top (Start, Stop, Pause, Restart, etc.) are grayed out. When I click Properties, I get an Access Denied, Error 5.

I have logged in as SYSTEM, and still get the same denial and error. Running SC from the command prompt will not touch it either. I have also tried starting in Safe Mode and logging on as Administrator.

File permissions for rasman.dll and rasmans.dll are set to Full for all users. It is not a file permission problem.

Bottom line: how do you reset (or else take ownership and then set) permissions for a service when no account seems to have access to it?

Comment: It's time to replace this machine with a new one running an OS that is still supported. XP no longer gets even basic security patches. If you leave it installed, look forward to doing this kind of work a lot more often.

Comment: Believe me, I would love to upgrade. But that is not going to happen today. I just need an answer to the question... someone out there knows exactly how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SYSTEM is not special – it cannot override DACLs just like Administrators cannot. However, Administrators always have the SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege...

- Using [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/): under the *Services* tab, open your service, go to *Security* → *Advanced*, and select "Change owner".
- Using [ProcExp](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) or Process Hacker: when the service is running, double-click its process, select *Services* → "Remote Access Connection" → *Permissions* → *Advanced*, use "Change owner".
- Directly via registry: navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SYSTEM \ CurrentControlSet \ Services \ RasMan \ Security, and delete the "Security" item. Reboot.

Comment: Deleting the registry item "Security" (actually, I renamed it for safety) and restarting fixed the problem.